# How to access a PRIVATE PUBLIC interface in Fortran?

Tags: interface, compilation, fortran, private, public

I have the following code:

```
SUBROUTINE test
USE mp, only: mp_bcast
integer :: B = 0
logical :: A
...
CALL mp_bcast (A, B)
END SUBROUTINE test
```

The problem is that the module mp goes as follow:

```
MODULE mp
IMPLICIT NONE
PRIVATE

PUBLIC :: mp_bcast
!
INTERFACE mp_bcast
  MODULE PROCEDURE mp_bcast_i1, mp_bcast_r1, mp_bcast_c1, mp_bcast_l  ! etc
END INTERFACE

SUBROUTINE mp_bcast_l(msg,source,gid)
  IMPLICIT NONE
  LOGICAL :: msg
  INTEGER, INTENT(IN) :: source
  INTEGER, INTENT(IN) :: gid
END SUBROUTINE mp_bcast_l
```

It is private but the interface is public. I cannot modify the module mp (belong to another software I want to interface to).

I use the following Makefile:

```
MODS = ../../Modules_mp/libmod.a
prog : prog.o test.o $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) -o prog.x $(MODS)
```

This way I though I could access the public interface in the module libmod.a that contains the module 'mp'. 
It does not work and I get this error:

```
test.f90(38): error #6285: There is no matching specific subroutine for this generic subroutine call.   [MP_BCAST]
  CALL mp_bcast (A,B)
-------^
```

What would be the correct way to proceed?

Thank you,

Samuel

Comment: From the error message, it looks like the problem is that you're just calling `mp_bcast`  with arguments of the wrong type, i.e. there is no procedure which can handle `A` and `B` whatever they are on the call from subroutine `test`. `mp_bcast` actually *is* public in module `mp`, so, you have to provide more context.

Comment: I think you're missing a third argument. The second and third arguments seem to be integers for all procedures under that interface.

Comment: Oh you are correct ! In version QE 4 the gid was optional but not anymore !
Thank you !!

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling a generic routine, the compiler goes through all its specific routines to find one that matches the type of the arguments. If it doesn't find one, this is the error message you get.

Have a close look at what types your `A` and `B` are, and see whether one of the specific routines matches it.

**Updated due to more information**

The specific subroutine you think matches has three dummy arguments (one logical, two integer), but you are only supplying two (logical and one integer).

*Note: below is my original answer, which some people commented on, so I'll leave it it.*

Maybe `A` is of type `REAL` and `B` is type `INTEGER`, so the compiler would search for a specific routine that has one `REAL` and one `INTEGER`, in that order, and doesn't find one. In that case, it might be necessary to convert one of the variables, like so:

```
CALL mp_bcast(A, float(B))
```

Note: From what you are writing:

```
MODULE PROCEDURE mp_bcast_i1, mp_bcast_r1, mp_bcast_c1  ! etc
```

I deduce that the `_i1` might stand for `INTEGER(KIND=1)`, and so forth, though I don't think that there is such a thing as `REAL(KIND=1)`.

Comment: It is my guess that [this](http://qe-forge.org/gf/project/q-e/scmsvn/?action=browse&path=%2Ftrunk%2Fespresso%2FModules%2Fmp.f90&view=markup) is the relevant source file. If so, the number 1 signals a scalar, not the kind.

Comment: I agree with this answer but, to be pernickety, *I don't think that there is such a thing as REAL(KIND=1)*  is a very compiler-dependent statement.  And wrong for at least one compiler currently in widespread use.

Comment: It is from QE source code indeed. 
I have updated the question. The subroutine 'mp_bcast_l' should match but I still have the compilation problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your use of private and public is correct, as is the text of the error message. The problem appears to be your invocation with only two arguments. Here's an example using genericswap.f90 (available online without the additions of `PRIVATE` and `PUBLIC swap` which I've added):

```
module swap_module
  implicit none
  PRIVATE
  PUBLIC swap
  interface swap
    module procedure swap_reals, swap_integers
  end interface
```

The compiler will look through the module procedures listed and identify the one that matches the signature. Your list `mp_bcast_i1, mp_bcast_r1, mp_bcast_c1, mp_bcast_l` appears to have no match with `(A,B)` (whatever type they are). I can't be entirely certain, as you've only given the source for one routine.

I know this is an old post, but I just wanted to make sure the information was available to others who wander down this path. It may also be necessary to check what is implemented by the compiler you're using. In my case I'm using `gfortran version 7.1.0 (Ubuntu 7.1.0-5ubuntu2~16.04)`.

Comment: Hi, don't use <code> for code blocks formatting. Use the icon in the editor which adds 4 spaces of indentation.